# Can not declare dependency to bblanchon/ArduinoJson in my library.json (platform io)

Tags: platformio, arduinojson

I am creating a platform IO library for one of my projects, which depends on [ArduinoJson from bblanchon](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson).

I have declared the dependency in my library.json file (both with the name as well as with the git repository as reference - see below). But when I try to compile a project that is using my library, the ArduinoJson library is not added to the dependency tree and compiling fails as the header file ArduinoJson.h is not found.

If I add the ArduinoJson as a dependency to the platformio.ini it is added to the dependency tree and the software compiles without issues. However this is not a clean solution and I want to now how I should declare the dependency in my library so that I do not have to add ArduinoJson to every project I build with this library.

Do you have any ideas how I can make this work?

Thx Christian

Declaration of dependency as suggested by pio library finder:

```
"dependencies" : 
{
    ...
    "bblanchon/ArduinoJson" : "*"
}
```

As reference to the repository

```
"dependencies" : 
{
    ...
    "bblanchon/ArduinoJson" : "https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson.git"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one had me going for a bit as well. Here are the steps I took to solve.

1. Add to *platformio.ini:*
   *lib_deps = Arduino-libraries/Arduino_JSON @ 0.1.0*
2. Verify that you have the folder */.pio/libdeps/Arduino_JSON*
3. Use *#include <Arduino_JSON>* in you code.

Comment: The Problem is not that I am able to add the library to plarformio.ini but I want to add it to one of my own libraries as dependency in the library.json file and this does not work. Do you have any ideas about that?